# Bootstrap Tour Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I am testing out Bootstrap Tour for a very simple test page that I have setup. The content displays but the tour functionality does not kick in for some reason. Could someone tell me what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Please find my code attached below

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> This is a testing page for bootstrap tour </title>

    <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bootstraptour/build/css/bootstrap-tour.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bootstraptour/build/css/bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
  ================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="../bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bootstraptour/build/js/bootstrap-tour.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bootstraptour/build/js/bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var tour = new Tour();

    // Add your steps. Not too many, you don't really want to get your users sleepy
    tour.addSteps([{
        element: "#content", // string (jQuery selector) - html element next to which the step popover should be shown
        title: "Title of my step", // string - title of the popover
        content: "Content of my step" // string - content of the popover
    }, {
        element: "#content1",
        title: "Title of my step",
        content: "Content of my step"
    }]);

    // Initialize the tour
    tour.init();

    // Start the tour
    tour.start();
</script>


<body>
    <div id="content">
        Hello, World!
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="content1">
        Another Hello, World!
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What version of Bootstrap? Also, you're missing a doctype, and the viewport meta tag.

Comment: Don't include both 'bootstrap-tour.min.js' and 'bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.js'. As you are using bootstrap, you should not include 'bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.js'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include **either** `bootstrap-tour.min.css/bootstrap-tour.min.js` (when you are including `bootstrap.min.css/bootstrap.min.js` yourself) or `bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.css/bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.js`, but not both. See the explanation on the [bootstrap tour homepage](http://bootstraptour.com/).

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var tour = new Tour();

// Add your steps. Not too many, you don't really want to get your users sleepy
tour.addSteps([{
  element: "#content", // string (jQuery selector) - html element next to which the step popover should be shown
  title: "Title of my step", // string - title of the popover
  content: "Content of my step" // string - content of the popover
}, {
  element: "#content1",
  title: "Title of my step",
  content: "Content of my step"
}]);

// Initialize the tour
tour.init();

// Start the tour
tour.start();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tour/0.11.0/js/bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tour/0.11.0/css/bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="content">
  Hello, World!
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="content1">
  Another Hello, World!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your local storage because bootstrap tour is using localStorage.